# Android MediaCodec: ExtractMpegFramesTest.java

Tags: android, android-mediacodec, mpeg-4

I am trying to run  `ExtractMpegFramesTest.java`  but getting an error :

```
[OMX.qcom.video.encoder.avc] storeMetaDataInBuffers (output) failed w/ err

Frame wait time out
```

Please advice me how to get out of this issue as no much related information online regarding this issue.

Comment: Can you please share the `logcat` dump? Frame wait out means that a buffer was given to your component which hasn't release the same within the specified timeout of 3s. The error reported is not a major issue.

Answer (score 0):

http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/#q12

Q12. Why am I seeing storeMetaDataInBuffers failures in the log?

A12. They look like this (example from a Nexus 5):

```
E OMXNodeInstance: OMX_SetParameter() failed for StoreMetaDataInBuffers: 0x8000101a 
E ACodec  : [OMX.qcom.video.encoder.avc] storeMetaDataInBuffers (output) failed w/ err -2147483648
```

You can ignore them, they're harmless.

For frame timeout you need to make processing in a separate thread, please look here: [Running ExtractDecodeEditEncodeMuxTest outside of testcase on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24733805/running-extractdecodeeditencodemuxtest-outside-of-testcase-on-android/24734088)

Comment: Thanks for your responce but i am not getting that, can you suggest me with some other options as when i comment out th.join() my Frame wait error gone but still facing the same issue.Please help on this.